# Scala с Android - есть у кого-нибудь опыт?

Tags: android, java, scala

Ау? Есть у кого-нибудь опыт со Scala в Android?

Синтаксис дюже нравится, а по сути все равно внутри все та же вроде Java - так что наверняка подойдет к Android

Comment: чего-то есть на хабре http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/136705/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Здесь пара плагинов для сборки приложений на Scala под Android:

- [Build Scala Android apps using Scala](https://github.com/jberkel/android-plugin).
- [Android Plugin for Gradle, featuring ProGuard and Scala support](https://github.com/jvoegele/gradle-android-plugin/wiki/)

Answer (score 10):

Опыт есть. Основная проблема -- андроид имеет свой формат архивов (вместо jar -- dex). В формате [есть ограничение в 65,535](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20814) методов/на файл и scala в это ограничение упирается. С этим можно бороться с помощью таких инструментов как proguard, которые вырезают весь неиспользуемый код, и делает еще ряд оптимизаций, но он работает отнюдь не быстро и каждый и так не быстрый цикл "собрал приложение/залил на телефон-эмулятор/протестировал" еще больше затягивается.

Раньше (до версии 2.2 когда вроде бы сделали JIT в андроиде) код написанный на scala был медленней чем plain java, теперь это разница не заметна. Заметна разница в потреблении памяти (но трудные места можно написать в императивном стиле -- scala позволяет, или же написать на java -- как тут упоминали, можно в одном проекте замиксовать любые jvm языки, которые компилируются в class файлы, это например Java, Scala, Clojure, Kotlin и другие менее популярные).

В остальном разработка довольно приятная (например, плагин про который упоминал @мурмурмур позволяет использовать типизированные ресурсы, а не кастовать каждый ресурс который выбираешь по id).

Answer (score 2):

У нас в команде пишут. Я правда сам не мобильный разработчик, бэкендом занимаюсь, но с отзывами самих разработчиков можете [здесь ознакомиться](http://eax.me/scala-doubts/). Пишут в Android Studio насколько я знаю. С точки зрения пользователя проблем с мобильным приложением замечено особых не было.

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать. В принципе, можно брать любой язык, который генерит class файлы для java 1.5 - 1.6. А андроид компилятор просто перегоняет их в dex файлы и пакует в архив apk. Более того, можно в одном проекте комбинировать в различных пропорциях разные языки.

Answer (score 1):

Вот здесь уже это обсуждалось:
[Добавление поддержки Scala за несколько кликов ...](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/android_development/136705/)

Может поможет :)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить посмотреть вот такую статейку ["Hello, World!" на Scala под Android](http://beizero.github.io/posts/2016-03-09-helloworld-on-android-with-scala.html)